# Delete elements in an array based on another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning the array methods in javascript. I want to delete elements in an array based on another array. I tried with the below approach but didn't get the expected result.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const array2 = [2, 4, 5];

array2.forEach(a2 => {
  array1.filter(a1 => a1 !== a2)
})

console.log(array1);
// actual output: Array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
// expected output: Array [1,3,6,7]
```

Which would be the best array method suited here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ***returns*** a new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

You have to reassign the returned value to the array. Please note, you can not reassign a *const* variable, use *var* or *let* instead.

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const array2 = [2, 4, 5];

array2.forEach(a2 => {
  array1 = array1.filter(a1 => a1 !== a2);
})

console.log(array1);
```

**Update:** There are some issues in the approach you are trying to achieve the result. There is no need to use `forEach()` here at all, you can simply use `filter()` and in each iteration check if the current item is not exists in *array2* using `includes()` like the following way:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const array2 = [2, 4, 5];
const array3 = array1.filter(a1 => !array2.includes(a1));
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I want to do more practice on these basic things. I need some questions to build logic on managing the array in Javascript. Any useful link would be better.

Comment: You are most welcome. As far as I know there is no such site you can get the logic help, you can master the array built-in functions which will help to implement any array manipulations:)

Comment: one more question If I want to store the returned array in another array say `array3` then how could I achieve that?

Comment: Actually, it showing me this `Array [1,2,3,4,6,7]` when I take `let array3=[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`ARRAY.filter` do not mutate the array. If possible, declare `array1` with `let` so that you can **reassign** it. (Just like the other answer)

By the way, you can use `ARRAY.includes(ELEMENT)` to check whether `ELEMENT` is in `ARRAY`. So you can simplify the code to:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const array2 = [2, 4, 5];

array1 = array1.filter(a1 => !array2.includes(a1));
console.log(array1);
```

or

```js
const array2 = [2, 4, 5];
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(a1 => !array2.includes(a1));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I'll try with this too